# wordpress - shopp plugin shop('cartitem','inputs')

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shopp

I am using shopp plugin in wordpress.

```
<?php shopp('cartitem','input'); ?>
```

i got result value "Testing" but if condition not working

```
<?php if(shopp('cartitem','input')=='Testing') ?>
```

if condition not working

If you using before shopp plugin please help me!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Shopp tag you are using `shopp('cartitem', 'input')` is just for displaying the value.

You should use `shopp('cartitem.get-input')` to use the value as a value.